# Why ubuntu does not have /usr/bin/bash

Tags: bash, symbolic-link

this is not a problem, just curious:
Why ubuntu does not have /usr/bin/bash ?

as link to /bin/bash or other direction.

Comment: Why should it have one?

Comment: Whether or not it is the right place for bash, a lot of utilities assume bash to be in /usr/bin/bash - if you look for example in most IDE's when they generate a template for a bash script they include '!#/usr/bin/bash' at the top. I think there is some legacy of that location being important and it would be nice if there was at least a symlink to it. Full-disclosure, I got bit by a utility that hard-coded /usr/bin/bash - a bad move sure - but if you can reduce the user pain due to bad moves by others, generally that is a win.

Comment: but the hard link is safer than the soft one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
oli@bert:~$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

Why would you expect it to be in `/usr/bin/` instead of `/bin/`? You'll see from the FHS that `/bin/` is supposed to be for essential userspace applications of which `bash` is most certainly one.

`/usr/bin/` is for less essential stuff.

Comment: I know this is old, but for clarification. Bash is not historically an essential userspace application, which is why the question is technically valid. For Ubuntu, though, one could argue it is definitely essential; but there are ways around that as well.